# Link not being processed

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

At [What kind of topological invariants can you get from just Hopf algebras?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80695/what-kind-of-topological-invariants-can-you-get-from-just-hopf-algebras), link [4] is not being processed:

[image: What kind of topological invariants can you get from just Hopf algebras? with link not processed]

However, it is there in the [source](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/7840fea0-55ec-411b-86a8-9e6c2eb6c3d0/view-source):

```
  [1]: http://www-math.mit.edu/~ptingley/publications/minus-sign.pdf
  [2]: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503040
  [3]: http://math.columbia.edu/~ellis/ugrad_seminar_spring_2011/geissinger.pdf
  [4]: http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/talks/Hopfzoo.pdf
```

Why isn't it processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you need to let the `<hr>` tag its own paragraph. I fixed it now.